# Taylor expansion of stochastic variables with dynamics of the form $dX_t=b(\sigma_t,X_t)dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility

https://www.math.nyu.edu/~cai/Courses/Derivatives/compfin_lecture_5.pdf

In the above document stochastic taylor expansions are nicely  explained.

Let us now consider a typical SDE model in finance like SABR. here the form is:

$$
dS_t=b(\sigma_t,S_t)dW_t
$$

My point is that because $b$ also depends on another stochastic variable, we cannot follow the simple steps provided in the document. Or can we ....... So my question, **how dos the Taylor expansion of $S_t$ look like in this setup?** To keep it simple we can just say first order, that is not not important.

And also: can we even derive the Taylor expansion if we dont know the dynamics of $\sigma_t$. I wonder if we can just say
$$dS_t=\sigma_t b(S_t)$$
and treat $\sigma_t$ as a "constant". How wrong would that be?